# Magento 2 - Go directly to the checkout page when adding a product to the cart

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I am writing an extension which allows to go directly to the checkout page when clicking on the add-to-cart button on the product page.  I found a solution for Magento 1 [here](http://www.magecorner.com/bypass-cart-and-go-to-checkout/) and I tried to adapt it to Magento 2. Here are my files:

File etc/frontend/events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer
            name="mycompany_go_to_checkout"
            instance="MyCompany\GoToCheckout\Observer\GoToCheckout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

File Observer/GoToCheckout.php:

```
namespace MyCompany\GoToCheckout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class GoToCheckout implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_url;

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('checkout');
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    }
}
```

What should I change or add to make it work?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What's not working at the moment? Have you checked to ensure that your observer is firing correctly?

Comment: I agree with Robbie, checking to see if it is firing in the first place I think is the first step.

Comment: I checked and it is firing.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the full working code. I used if for my module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer
            name="mycompany_go_to_checkout"
            instance="MyCompany\GoToCheckout\Observer\GoToCheckout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And observer code is:

```
namespace MyCompany\GoToCheckout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class GoToCheckout implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $uri;
    protected $responseFactory;
    protected $_urlinterface;

 public function __construct(
        \Zend\Validator\Uri $uri,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlinterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
         \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->uri = $uri;
        $this->_urlinterface = $urlinterface;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setRedirect($this->_urlinterface->getUrl('checkout'))->sendResponse('200');
        exit();
    }
}
```

But this code only works for detail page. In listing page it will not work because its managed by Ajax. So what was the solutions for that? Easy, just create one Plugin for **Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php** and write your logic in this file.

Comment: I am trying to redirect to checkout from product detail page, but this is not working in magento 2.2.5. Also can you tell me, how to redirect from plugin?

Comment: Can you please say the steps to implement this code? I am new for making plugins in magento.

Answer (score 2):

you must use following code to redirect from Observer in Magento2

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
  $redirect = $observer->getEvent()->getRedirect();
  $redirect->setRedirect(true)->setPath('checkout')->setArguments([]);
  return $this;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and I added some log outputs to follow the flow. I appears it stops at the second line:
`$redirect->setRedirect(true)->setPath('checkout')->setArguments([]);`

There is no additional information in the log files.

Comment: Throwing exception "Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setRedirect() on null in /path_to_module_observer/observer.php:100"

Answer (score 2):

Magento already provide these setting with admin settings,

Magento1

```
Admin > System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart > After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart >YES.
```

Magento2

```
Admin-> Store ->Configuration->Sales->Checkout ->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart
```

Set Dropdown value as requirements,

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 use this code in Observer:

```
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $this->urlInterface->getUrl('checkout'));
        return $this;
    }
```