# How to redirect to checkout page after add to cart on single product page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2

I want to redirect the user to the checkout page on Adding product to cart, Please help.

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115039/redirect-to-home-page-in-controller

Comment: @shinoy shaji Please read my question again and I'm talking about Magento 2. Thanks for your time

Comment: Have a look on [Magento 2 - Go directly to the checkout page when adding a product to the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536452/magento-2-go-directly-to-the-checkout-page-when-adding-a-product-to-the-cart) and [Magento 2: Skipping Shopping Cart Page after Add to Cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138035/magento-2-skipping-shopping-cart-page-after-add-to-cart)

Comment: Thanks to all for their answers. I resolved it by myself.

Comment: how you do it??

Comment: @alexeyboltynov Please check my answer and accept it if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

@alexeyboltynov First you have enable skip cart option from magento 2 admin. you can found that option easily in your theme settings.

And you have to overwrite core file path: 
"vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart\Add.php"

Find code:

```
if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
    if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
        if ($this->shouldRedirectToCart()) {
            $message = __(
                'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                     $product->getName()
                );
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
        } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                            'addCartSuccessMessage',
                            [
                                'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                                'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                            ]
                        );
                    }
                }
                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
            }
```

**Replace it with:**

```
if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
           return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout', ['_current' => true]);
            }
```

This will redirect users to the checkout page after adding product to cart. And removed success add to cart messages.

**Note:** Please make you own custom module for this don't overwrite the core file. Hope you know how to create your own module.